# Function call not working after migrating to null safe flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have defined a function to get some information from the server

```
@override
  Future<HttpResponse<dynamic>> getAppInfo() async {
    const _extra = <String, dynamic>{};
    final queryParameters = <String, dynamic>{};
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    final _result = await _dio.fetch(_setStreamType<HttpResponse<dynamic>>(
        Options(method: 'GET', headers: <String, dynamic>{}, extra: _extra)
            .compose(_dio.options, '/user/app-info',
                queryParameters: queryParameters, data: _data)
            .copyWith(baseUrl: baseUrl ?? _dio.options.baseUrl)));
    final value = _result.data;
    final httpResponse = HttpResponse(value, _result);
    return httpResponse;
  }
```

I am passing this function as an argument at run time to different function. Another function is defined this way

```
Future<HttpResponse?> handleApi(
    Function function, [
    List<dynamic>? args,
  ]) async {
    try {
      final HttpResponse httpResult = await Function.apply(
        function,
        args,
      ) as HttpResponse; // This following bloc of code is not getting called

      if (httpResult.response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok ||
          httpResult.response.statusCode == HttpStatus.created) {
        return httpResult;
      }
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

And i am passing first function to second function as an argument. It was working fine without null safe version of flutter. And after the migration to null safe, the call is not happening on the function at run time.

I am calling handleApi fucntion following way

```
final httpResultOrError = await _apiCallHandler.handleApi(
     getAppInfo,
 );
```

Comment: What happens?  If you're observing that nothing happens, perhaps first stop silently swallowing all `Exception`s and seeing if there's a failure you're ignoring.

Comment: I tried to remove the `try catch` statement as well, no exception is thrown, nothing is happening, It's just silently failing there

Comment: Have you tried calling the getAppInfo just by iteself without passing in it to the handleApi method?